# Bath tub supports?

Tags: bathtub

I have just removed our bath panel before i install out new one and to clear out any grime that has gotten in there.

To my surprise it is clean and dry, but another question came up.

Is it normal for the tub to be supported with chipboard between the metal bars and the tub itself?

Comment: A picture would be great to see what you have. I am not familiar with "metal bars and the tub itself".

Comment: I'll get a picture tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there could be wood, roof shingles, cardboard, drywall, plaster, cement or even spray foam. If the tub's bottom is solid to walk or stand on then you're good to re-enclose. If it's bouncy or spongy then you'll want to add to what's there or replace with a make up that's snug to the entire bottom, if you care or cracks in the finish have you worried.